# 90 degrees rotation of 2D isometric game

Tags: unity, isometric

I am learning unity and wandering how to rotate an isometric map at 90 degrees.

I have a fixed grid about 96x96 and would like to implement rotation of my game scene.

Now I am wandering what approach is the best opption:

1. Create a basic game in ortographic projection and use ortograpic sprites and then change camera's view angles. It seems possible to rotate grid in ortographic projection and then change camera's view anles again.
2. Create a game in isometric projection and use isometric sprites. Here I have a problem because if I rotate an isometric diamond shape sprite at 90 degree it look not as I deserved (I expect to see it from 120 degrees always). So it seems that I need to have 4 copies of each tile for each rotation angle. And I need to change sprites after rotation. I am thinking about perfomance, will the game still work normally, bcs there are a huge amount of tiles need to be rerendered.
3. Smth else

What approach do you recommend?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without understanding the art style you want to create. Do you have any mockups or other reference images of how you want your game to look?